# how to pass and access path parameters in aws api gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am new in web development and trying to learn AWS.
I have made a lambda function for listing.
What I am doing here is I am showing listing, if I get counteId in params(URL) then it shows only data of that counter id else it shows all data.
My lambda function was working fine. But I am having a problem while API integration.

[this is how I am accessing pathparameters which are in the event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUVdH.png)

[this is how I am configuring event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYJE5.png)

[and this is my query and response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA8LS.png)

then I create an API gateway for it.
[this is what I did while creating Resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKXRE.png)

[/{proxy+} - ANY - Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8NaE.png)

I want to get only data of counterId 1, but I am getting whole data.
[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlrfJ.png)

My HTTPmethod is "ANY" and I choose lambda proxy integration in request integration.
I don't know how to send path parameters. Kindly help me.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question so that as much of possible of the material is pasted in as text; screenshots make it hard for the community to help you. Thanks.

Comment: @MandyShaw ok, i'll keep that in mind and will edit this post. ThanK you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit 'Mapping Template' in 'Integration Request' of you method properties in API Gateway.

You could find how to map it in [API Gateway Mapping Template Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html) article, in the 'Accessing the $input Variable' section.

Your template has to look like next:

```
{
    "name" : "$input.params('name')",
    "body" : $input.json('$') 
}
```

Check out more details in my answer to [the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52105719/182344).

Comment: but i am doing it with lambda proxy intigration. there is no such option for lambda proxy intigration