# AWS Lambda handler implementation for "API Gateway" document?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Where is document for AWS Lambda Programming model with "API Gateway"?

For example,

```
  What fields are there in handler's request params? 
  (headers, queryParameter, ...)

  What fields should be there for handler's response? 
  (statusCode, body, ...)
```

I saw some code example for Lambda and API Gateway. 
But I cann't find reference documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You could find it in [API Gateway Mapping Template Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html) article, in the 'Accessing the $input Variable' section.

Also, you could check my answer for [the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52105719/182344).

Your template has to look like next:

```
{
    "name" : "$input.params('name')",
    "body" : $input.json('$') 
}
```